# Checking for text boxes not null

Tags: c#

If I have two text boxes and I want to know if both of their `Text` properties are null I can do this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNameFirst.Text) && 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNameLast.Text))
    {}
```

That will check if both *are* null or blank, but is there a way to say if *not* null or white space? Essentially, the inverse?

Comment: `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`?

Comment: You can prefix the statements with a logical Not (!) like `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNameFirst.Text)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a `!` before the `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` method call.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNameFirst.Text) && 
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNameLast.Text)) 
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNameFirst.Text) && 
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNameLast.Text))
    {}
```

or

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNameFirst.Text) == false && 
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNameLast.Text) == false)
    {}
```

or

```
if (txtNameFirst.Text?.Trim().Length > 0 && 
    txtNameLast.Text?.Trim().Length > 0)
    {}
```

Comment: I haven't come across .text?.property before. Could you point me in the direction of some further information on the '?' used in this way. Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Comment: @B.Hawkins if `Text` is `null` somehow, accessing `Length` would not throw a `NullReferenceException`, as it otherwise would do. That means, it is an inline check for `null`.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann Thank's. I was aware of the ?? operator but had not come across the single ? used in this way.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann: although nicely demonstrating the null-conditional operator - your last example would fail is either string contained only white-space. It should be _"txtNameFirst.Text?.Trim().Length > 0"_

Comment: @PaulF but what if I set the value of `Text` to `null`? I have just checked it again; it works...

Comment: Try setting both strings to spaces - the first two examples return false, your final example without trimming returns true, with trimming it returns false. Your code is equivalent to ! IsNullOrEmpty trimming makes it ! IsNullOrWhiteSpace.

Comment: @PaulF Now I see what you mean. Thanks for pointing it out; I have edited the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else is saying, `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` will work for you.

Based on this question I assume you didn't know this, but the logical negation operator `!` is a unary operator that negates its operand. It is defined for bool and returns true if and only if its operand is false.

So another example, let's say I want to see if the string `The dog barked loudly` contains the letter `a`, I would type `string.Contains("a")`. However, if I wanted to to make sure it *does not* contain the letter `a`, I would type `!string.Contains("a")`.